# cannot launch node in hydro

Tags: navigation, ros-hydro, amcl, move-base, node

[image: Rosanswers logo]

When i  launch move_base.launch, I got this :

```
ERROR: cannot launch node of type [tf/static_transform_publisher]: can't locate node [static_transform_publisher] in package [tf]
ERROR: cannot launch node of type [amcl/amcl]: can't locate node [amcl] in package [amcl]
```

However I already have done : `sudo apt-get install ros-hydro-amcl` and `sudo apt-get install ros-hydro-tf`

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/188139/cannot-launch-node-in-hydro/) by [Moda](https://answers.ros.org/users/19573/moda/) on ROS Answers with karma: 133 on 2014-07-29

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [BennyRe](https://answers.ros.org/users/3675/bennyre/) on 2014-07-29**:
What happens if you do roscd tf?

**Comment by [Moda](https://answers.ros.org/users/19573/moda/) on 2014-07-29**:
/opt/ros/hydro/share/tf$

**Comment by [Moda](https://answers.ros.org/users/19573/moda/) on 2014-07-29**:
and for amcl : /opt/ros/hydro/share/amcl

**Comment by [sterlingm](https://answers.ros.org/users/2199/sterlingm/) on 2014-07-29**:
Can you post your ROS_PACKAGE_PATH environment variable?

**Comment by [Moda](https://answers.ros.org/users/19573/moda/) on 2014-07-29**:
What is my ROS_PACKAGE_PATH ? the path for the catkin_ws  folder?
If yes it is /home/lempereur/catkin_ws
and the path for the hydro is /opt/ros/hydro/

**Comment by [sterlingm](https://answers.ros.org/users/2199/sterlingm/) on 2014-07-29**:
Do "env | grep ROS" and you will see it. It is the path where ROS looks for your packages. But if roscd takes you where you listed it is probably fine. Do "ls /opt/ros/hydro/lib/tf" and see if it lists the static_transform_publisher executable.

**Comment by [Moda](https://answers.ros.org/users/19573/moda/) on 2014-07-29**:
My ROS_PACKAGE_PATH is
ROS_PACKAGE_PATH=/opt/ros/hydro/share:/opt/ros/hydro/stacks

**Comment by [Moda](https://answers.ros.org/users/19573/moda/) on 2014-07-29**:
when I maid ls /opt/ros/hydro/lib/tf I get bullet_migration_sed.py  static_transform_publisher  tf_change_notifier  tf_echo  tf_empty_listener  tf_monitor  tf_remap  view_frames

**Comment by [BennyRe](https://answers.ros.org/users/3675/bennyre/) on 2014-07-29**:
Ok static_transform_publisher exists. Do ls -l /opt/ros/hydro/lib/tf to see if it's executable.

**Comment by [Moda](https://answers.ros.org/users/19573/moda/) on 2014-08-01**:
I got this : -rwxr-xr-x 1 root root  18872 juin  17 10:57 static_transform_publisher

**Comment by [Moda](https://answers.ros.org/users/19573/moda/) on 2014-08-01**:
And even for amcl I have this : -rwxr-xr-x 1 root root 620296 juil. 23 21:42 amcl

**Comment by [dido_yf](https://answers.ros.org/users/21158/dido_yf/) on 2014-12-18**:
hello, I have the same problem with you. Did you solve this problem? Could you tell me how?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I deleted all the files from my workspace, and reinstall everythink. And it solves my error.
Thank you for your help BennyRe and Sterlingm.
However, i got this error :

```
Waiting on transform from base_link to map to become available before running costmap, tf error: 
[ WARN] [1406882852.669591743]: No laser scan received (and thus no pose updates have been published) for 1406882852.669489 seconds.  Verify that data is being published on the /scan topic.
```

I already faced this issue in groovy, and i was unable to found a solution.
http://answers.ros.org/question/187967/groovy-how-to-link-scan-to-base_link/

---

Originally posted by [Moda](https://answers.ros.org/users/19573/moda/) with karma: 133 on 2014-08-01

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0